# Controlling Navigation with Pagecontainer Widget in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use Pagecontainer widget for page navigation.
I would like to have some kind of control over enabling/disabling navigation with it.
Is it possible to have info 'navigation active', or to disable/enable navigation?

Following two simplified examples should be enough to describe what I would like to achieve.

```
function loginIfRequired() {
    if(isRequired) $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#loginPage');
}


loginIfRequired();
if(!pagecontainerIsNavigationActive()) {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#someOtherPage');
}
```

or

```
function loginIfRequired() {
    if(isRequired) $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#loginPage');
    pagecontainerNavigationDisable(true);
}


$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#someOtherPage');
pagecontainerNavigationDisable(false);
```

Is there a way to achieve `pagecontainerIsNavigationActive` or `pagecontainerNavigationDisable`functionality? Or maybe some other way to control Pagecontainer widget which would solve my problem?

Comment: at which stage you want to disable navigation? you want to prevent user from accessing certain pages or lock him/her in page?

Comment: I want to prevent accessing any page if certain conditions apply. In the first example if I remove `pagecontainerIsNavigationActive`, user will first see `#loginPage` and then `#someOtherPage`. I don't want user to go to `#someOtherPage`.